# Use Roland D20 with Ableton Live Looper

Tags: midi-controller-keyboard, ableton-live

Can I use a simple sustain pedal with my Roland D-20 in order to do overdubbing with Ableton Live Looper audio effect? In other words, use the pedal for controlling the Looper All-purpose button that starts/stops recording/playback/overdubbing, etc.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Roland's D-20  is now a pretty old piece of kit. But MIDI Spec was solidly established and implemented by that time so that if you already have the D-20 set up as your main MIDI Controller for Live then Sustain Pedal performance info should be passed to the software along with Notes, Mod Wheel etc.

Comment: I just confirm that I have been using the Roland D20 for playing vst instruments setup in Live, having connected it's MiDI OUT port with the MIDI IN of a M-Audio Audiophile 2496 card that I use.  So it surely passes notes and other MIDI data along Ableton.